# Mac desktop background image not able to remove

Tags: mac

Last year I found a website telling how to add non-mac background image. I entered the code in the terminal and it was good. But now I am not able to find how to remove this image. It is not in /Library/Desktop Pictures. I try to find the file name, but it is not in my laptop. How can remove this?

I use MacOS Sierra v 10.12.5

[image]

[image]

Comment: What was the command? Have you tried searching where the command stores the image?

Comment: I don't remember the command. I tried to find from the image, but not able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a command that you can use to show you where the current wallpaper "lives."

1. Open a terminal and issue the following command:

   `defaults write com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text -bool TRUE;killall Dock`
2. Go to your desktop. The path should be visible on your wallpaper
3. To hide the path again just replace the `-bool TRUE` with `-bool FALSE`

Source: [Show the Location Path of Current Wallpaper in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/20/show-the-location-path-of-current-wallpaper-in-mac-os-x/)